# An error occurred on gearapi, react.development.js:1309 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'env')

Tags: javascript, web3js

"@gear-js/api": "^0.36.7",
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2zYft.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TJUl4.png)

Above is my operation steps, hope to have a teacher to answer

wiki address: https://wiki.gear-tech.io/docs/api/getting-started

I hope Solve the error, can use gear-js normally

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.